# Yarn There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: npm, hadoop-yarn

Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe its a firewall problem,
check if you are using proxy,
sometime its a problem of internet service provider

Comment: If so, how to fix it.